# Nested Callbacks with NodeJS & MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have come to a time in my java-script adventure where I have needed to nest callbacks. I have the following code. I keep reading bout nested callbacks being hell... if someone could explain or help with the code. I am still very new to asynchronous programming. I am using `nodejs`, `express 3.0`, `jade`, `node-mysql`

```
db_helper.getCategory(function (category) {
    db_helper.getCities(function (cities) {
             res.render('/search', category: category, cities: cities });

    });
});
```

i apologize for not really asking. Im wondering if this is ok to do this? Whats a better way to handle nested callbacks?

Comment: Sometimes I use Step module for that purpose, give it a look at https://github.com/creationix/step .

Comment: You haven't really asked a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) npm module.  It helps with organizing callbacks and avoiding the deep nesting you are referring to.  Perhaps the [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) would help.